# Use keys with value in json

Tags: javascript, json

i have this json

```
var person = {
   first_name: 'John',
   last_name: 'Doe',
   full_name: ?
}
```

How can use for the full name the previous two keys? (first_name,last_name)

Comment: You have to use a separate statement.

Comment: You mean a different json object?

Comment: No, a separate statement. You cannot do it at all if all you've got is pure JSON.  (What you posted is not correct JSON syntax however; that's JavaScript.)

Comment: ok,i see. Yes, json for javascript. I should put in the title i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var person = {
   first_name: 'John',
   last_name: 'Doe'
};

person.full_name = person.first_name + ',' + person.last_name;
```

At least that's the format you asked for: (first_name,last_name)

Alternatively, you could store the names in separate strings:

```
var first_name = 'John',
    last_name = 'Doe',
    person = {
       first_name: first_name,
       last_name: last_name,
       full_name: first_name + ',' + last_name
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So it's not possible when you initially build the json? I do need a different statement

Comment: @dianikol Not unless you store the strings in a separate variable